# convert LDAP date into normal human date?

Tags: python, pandas

Using LDAP a dataset has been pulled from Active Directory. The date looks like "20180111120926.0Z" and it has been loaded into pandas DataFrame. How do I convert it to a normal date?

Comment: just refer here I think the second function is you are looking for : https://gist.github.com/Mostafa-Hamdy-Elgiar/9714475f1b3bc224ea063af81566d873

Comment: Taking into account that there are several date formats and even calendars: what is a *normal* date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you need ?

```
pd.to_datetime('20180111120926.0Z',format='%Y%m%d%H%M%S.%fZ')
Out[734]: Timestamp('2018-01-11 12:09:26')
```